Restricting internet Traffic to a website(Frontdoor->appgateway->appservice)
We have a website hosted on an appservice. When the user hits the url, it uses below flow.
Frontdoor-> app gateway -> appservice
Appservice has custom domain added.
Appservice has below network configuration.
Private endpoint added

Enabled with access restrictions
Any Unmatched rule -> Deny
Deny all

But, right now its allowing traffic from the internet(through frontdoor) even if we used above configuration. I want to block any requests coming from the internet.

Maybe try asking over on https://superuser.com

Are you using private endpoints?

If you use your Application Gateway with an App Service as a Backend pool that is only inside a VNET, that means you have also a Private IP Configuration and your Application Gateway is deployed on a subnet.
You need to deploy a Network Security Group on your subnet where the Application Gateway is.
There you can just deny any connection that comes from the Internet (Inbound).
Your calls from the Internet will still reach Azure Front Door (that's the point though for this service). But then it will be blocked by your Subnet NSG at Application Gateway Level and won't go through the App Service.
Adding WAF on your Application Gateway can also enhance your security by having specific rules on your data packets, although this won't be your main "security" protection mechanism.
To sum up, you should reach for this:

